# C# - Pass reference between Parent & Child control

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a control which combines of 2 controls together - combobox and datagridview. I need a reference of both in many places of code in both classes. What I did for communicating is this

```
 public class CustomCombobox : ComboBox
 {
      public static CustomCombobox cmb;
      private CustomDataGridView My_DGV = new CustomDataGridView();

   protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
           cmb=this;
        }
}

 public class CustomDataGridView: DataGridView
    {
 protected override void OnCellClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCellClick(e);

            if (e.RowIndex > -1)
            {
                //Send some text to CustomCombobox
                Sending_text(CustomCombobox.cmb);
            }
        }
}
```

This is only an example of what I'm doing. But as you can see I override properties in both classes, so I need a reference to same instances of both controls. Output control is actually a Combobox with custom dropdown (ToolStripDropDown), and It works If only one control is added on form. When I added second one references got mixed up - text is sending from one combobox dropdown to another combobox, instead of sending to same combobox.

Can someone show me the easiest way for passing reference of each control instance in both ways ?

Comment: You might want to research `UserControls`,  These are great for sets of controls which need to work together.  Generally one control getting into another's business is a bad idea

Comment: Consider adding a constructor so you can pass the reference.  Using *static* to fix OOP programming problems is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: @Plutonix I was looking into that when I created this control, but nowhere to find an example with doing It as a UserControl. It's a comobbox with custom dropdown, created by a ToolStripDropDown + toolStripControlHost method. There is a lot of overriding methods in my case, that's why I went this way.

Comment: @RacilHilan Odd that you'd say it's not possible when the OP has shown the code that does it.  It's not hard at all to create a new type that extends another type of control, or for such a control to itself have other child controls.  A `UserControl` is *one* way of doing that; extending an existing control is another.  They're each appropriate in different situations.

Comment: Again, a UserControl can be ideal for this sort of thing.  Make your special combo, but seat it and the DGV on a UserControl.  The UC catches events and "tells" the other control to do this or that.  Much better than custom controls which are coded to interact with some other control.  They ought not even be aware of each other

Comment: @Plutonix, ok I'll try to do It, but where to find some example with mixing 2 controls with ToolStripDropDown ? As told, I didn't find any examples earlier, all I found was something simmilar to this or extremely complicated.

Comment: A UserControl is a bit like a form. Add a UserControl to the project.  Create your fancy CBO.  Build the project. Add a DGV and FancyCBO from the toolbox to the UserControl canvas.  Take baby steps - make a simple UC with standard controls to learn how they work, *then* add your fancy cbo and actual logic

Comment: @Plutonix, I'll have that in mind for next time, looks like I went wrong way. But for now I'll stick with Servy suggestion, I figured out a way to change It doing his suggestion and that takes much less effort at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is  you've written your data grid view to update the text of whatever combobox was most recently created.  You don't want to do that.  This is why `static` state should generally be avoided.  There isn't one single `CustomComboBox` in your whole application that is the one you want to update.

Your custom modifications should be mirroring the behavior of the control that you're extending.  That is, when you want to have a parent control be able to do something in response to a UI action you have an *event* that you fire.  That's what `DataGridView` is doing with its `CellClick` event, so that's what *your* control should do to, through your own event if needed.

Defining the event is nice and easy, and you can subscribe to the DGV's CellClick and fire your own event in that handler:

```
public class CustomDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    //TODO come up with meaningful name to represent the action that's taking place, 
    //and to differentiate it from CellClick
    public event Action<string> YourNewEvent;

    public CustomDataGridView()
    {
        CellClick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.RowIndex >= 1)
            {
                string text = GenerateTextToSendOnClick();
                YourNewEvent?.Invoke(text);
            }
        };
    }

    private string GenerateTextToSendOnClick()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The combo box is then free to subscribe to that event and do whatever it needs to do when the DGV has text for it:

```
public class CustomCombobox : ComboBox
{
    private CustomDataGridView dataGridView = new CustomDataGridView();
    public CustomCombobox()
    {
        dataGridView.YourNewEvent += DoStuffWithText;
    }

    private void DoStuffWithText(string text)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that this has an important advantage in that the custom DGV never needs to know anything about whatever classes might use it.  This means that it can be used by a ComboBox, or any other type of custom control that might want to use it, because all it ever does is fire an event that *any* parent of the control can freely use.

Comment: thanks for this, I'll try It. But what about a simple lines, where in my Combobox class I just need to do something with Datagridview in overrided voids ? - for instance, in Combobox OnDropDown I need a line **my_dgv.ClearSelection();**

Comment: @Lucy82 If you want to subscribe to the DropDown event of the combobox, then do that.  If you want to clear the DGV selection in it, it's already an instance variable.  What's the problem?

Comment: thank you very much for all your effort, I figured out a way and It was quite easy, I've allready completed, now everything works fine. Happy valentine's day ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the combobox is going to stay inside the gridview, you can put the combobox inside your custom gridview class and set it before you use it. Like this:

```
public class CustomDataGridView: DataGridView
{
    public CustomCombobox CustomCmb { get;set }

    protected override void OnCellClick(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCellClick(e);

        if (e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            //Send some text to CustomCombobox
            CustomCmb.ReceiveText(text); //Create this method in the custom combobox class, to separate responsibilities.
        }
    }
}
```

And remove the static variable `public static CustomCombobox cmb;` from the custom combobox class. Because in this case the same ComboBox will be accessed from all CustomDataGrids instead of a separate instance for each one.

Comment: thanks for this. But unfortunally that won't do, I need a reference to DatagridView from Combobox too. "ReceiveText" is actually a void where text from DataGridView row values is being sent to Combobox. So doing this method inside Combobox class brings me to start - I don't have acces to DataGridView instance to write a method. Or should I do same get; set; method in Combobox class ? Sorry gentlemens, I'm quite new to C# and I'm struggling so hard with this :)

Comment: on a second thought, It's quite opposite - gridview is inside combobox dropdown, so this won't work.